# Precision loss with double C++

Tags: c++

I'm developing a C++ application that runs on linux environment. I need to store a large value with 6 decimal places. I used a double for that, but after assigning it, it didn't contain the exact value. It was rounded off.

Ex:

```
double dValue = 79447461534242.913072; //Assignement of value
```

But after doing that , whenever I see the value of dValue, it is something like 79447461534242.906

Can some one let me know why this is happening and suggest me the correct data type which can hold the exact value without losing any precision.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Don't forget to accept your favourite answer ;)

Answer (score 8):

In a typical implementation, a `double` has about 15 digits of precision *total*. It doesn't matter much whether those are before or after the decimal point, it's just a total of 15 digits.

In your case, the original number is about 20 digits, so five are lost immediately.

Comment: Are you sure about the 15 digit precision in *total*? At least in Javascript integer precision is accurate ... But I am not sure whether this is something unique to Javascript.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer: Integer types are precise in C++ too; but this question is about floating-point types.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer: `double` and integer are two entirely different sorts of animals. While "higher level" languages often support arbitrary precision integers, C++ is usually implemented with what the hardware provides -- typically 16 bits for short, 32 for int, either 32 or 64 bits for long, and 64 for long long. `double` is normally a 64-bit floating point type with a 53-bit mantissa.

Comment: Javascript only offers a single `number` type which is always stored as a floating point number internaly. But they claim integer arithmetic is precise, thats why I am asking. I am aware that C++ has a more ... complete ... approach to number types.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer: A typical double will do precise integer arithmetic within the range of (about) -2^53..2^53. If they're maintaining precision outside that range, they must be using a different type (probably implemented in software, not directly in the CPU).

Comment: The claim I have heard that "integer arithmetic in Javascript is always precise" is plainly wrong. It uses indeed nothing but "ordinary" floating point numbers (http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#FAQ4_7). Another lesson learnt ...

Answer (score 6):

C++ uses IEEE floating point types which are only precise to a certain degree **by design**. If you need arbitary precision take a look at eg [GNU MP Bignum](http://gmplib.org/) or any other arbitary precision library.

Answer (score 2):

The [most commonly used double precision format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) stores the number with 53 bits of precision. This gives approximately 16 decimal digits of precision.

You may find that `long double` gives more precision, but there is no guarantee that that is any larger than `double`.

If you need more precision than you can get from native machine types, you will need a high-precision numeric library, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 2):

On linux you can use __float128 which is a quadruple precision floating point type.

Comment: I could not compile it with __float28. It gives the error ‘__float128’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: What version are you using of gcc?  Type `gcc --version`