# Losing Double Precision when multiplying by multiple of 10

Tags: c++

So I have the following code

```
int main(){

double d;
cin>>d;

while(d!=0.00)
{
    cout<<d<<endl;
    double m = 100*d;
    int n = m;
    cout<<n<<endl;
    cin>>d;
}

return 0;}
```

When I enter the input 20.40 for d the value of n comes out to be 2039 instead of 2040.
I tried replacing `int n = m`  with `int n = (int) m` but the result was the same.
Is there any way to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `std::round`. Floating-point numbers are not exact.

Comment: Floating point values are represented internally that way that your `20.40` can be `20.39999999999`. And `2039.999999` casted to int will be `2039`

Comment: This question comes up pretty regularly ([first such example I found](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12096852/1171191)). The answer is, of course, [goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: To build on the above because they are exact, but not exactly what you want, you could hack by adding 0.5 and then multiplying

Comment: (int)x always rounds to zero (it behaves like floor(x)). If you want to make it behave like round(x), you may try (int)(x + 0.5). It is not the best way, however, but it works in most cases.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov (and others) Please don't open that can of worms here. This is a tricky issue that needs a long answer with lots of references, probably best just as a link to a suitable answer. For instance, [this](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1) will explain what is wrong with `(int)(x+0.5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code truncates m but you need rounding. Include `cmath` and use `int n = round(m)`.

Comment: Thank You! Seems to have fixed it

Comment: You should note that `round` will actually round the number.  That is,  round(4.5) returns 5.  This may or may not be what he is after.

Answer (score 2):

Decimal values can, in general, not be represented exactly using binary floating points like `double`. Thus, the value `20.40` is represented as an approximation which can be used to restore the original value (`20.4`; the precision cannot be retained), e.g., when formatting the value. Doing computations with these approximated values will typically amplify the error.

As already mentioned in one of the comments, the relevant reference is the [paper](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf) "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic". One potential way out of your trouble is to use decimal floating points which are, however, not [yet](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3407.html) part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Single and double presicion floating point numbers are not stored the same way as integers, so whole numbers (e.g. 5, 10) may actually look like long decimals (e.g. 4.9999001, 10.000000001).  When you cast to an `int`, all it does is truncate the whole number.  So, if the number is currently represented as `4.999999999`, casting it to an `int` will give you `4`.  `std::round` will provide you with a better result most of the time (if the number is 4.6 and you just want the whole number portion, round will not work well).  The bigger question is then:  what are you hoping to accomplish by casting a `double` to an `int`?

In general, when dealing with floating point numbers, you will want to use some *epsilon* value that is your minimum significant digits.  So if you wanted to compare 4.9999999 to 5, you would do (pseudo-code): `if abs(5 - 4.9999999) < epsilon, return 5`.

**Example**

```
int main()
{
    double d;
    std::cin >> d;

    while (std::fabs(d - 0.0) > DBL_EPSILON)
    {
        std::cout << d << std::endl;
        double m = 100 * d;
        int n = static_cast<int>(m);
        if (std::fabs(static_cast<double>(n) - m) > DBL_EPSILON)
        {
            n++;
        }
        std::cout << n << std::endl;
        std::cin >> d;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting double to int truncates value so 20.40 is probably 20.399999 * 100 is 2039.99 because double is not base 10. You can use round() function that will not truncate but will get you nearest int.

```
int n = round(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers can't exactly represent all decimal numbers, sometimes an approximation is used. In your example the closest possible exact number is 20.39999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375. See [IEEE-754 Analysis](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) for a quick way to see exact values.

You can use rounding, but presumably you're really looking for the first two digits truncated.  Just add a really small value, e.g. 0.0000000001 before or after you multiply.